# partition a number N into K tuples

Tags: combinatorics

Given an integer $N ≥ 0$ and an integer $K ≥ 0$,  how many tuples $(n_1,\ldots,n_k)$ are there such that $n_i ≥0$ and $\Sigma n_i = N$?   In other words, how many way can you "partition" $N$ into $K$ sets such that the sum of the sets adds up to $N$.

For example, $n = 5$, $k =2$  gives 6 tuples:  $(5,0) , (4,1)  \ldots (0,5)$.

I've come up with this recursive definition:

> $P(n,k) =$ # of tuples $(n_1,..,n_k)$ such that $n_i ≥ 0$ and $\Sigma n_i = N$
>   $P(n,k) = \Sigma_{i=0}^n{P(i,k-1)}$
>   $P(0,k)=1   $
>   $P(n,1)=1$

A suggested answer below is that this problem is the Stirling #'s of 2nd kind but I am not sure how to reduce this problem to it.  See my response below.

My question is if there's a closed form solution for $P(n,k)$?

Comment: I would be very unsurprised if this is a duplicate.  If someone less busy than me would be happy to have a check for that, that would be great!

Comment: @Tara: You’re right: it’s about the umpty-third question involving this problem or a variant.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:  Are there enough of them to make one of those 'generalisations of common questions'?

Comment: @Tara: It would be a chore, because while some are very straightforward, like this one, some have fairly ugly boundary conditions. You can get a pretty good idea if you use the site search on *stars and bars*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:  Okay, yes, probably too much work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard [stars-and-bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29) problem; the answer is that $$p(n,k)=\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}=\binom{n+k-1}n=\frac{(n+k-1)!}{(k-1)!\,n!}\;.$$ The explanation in the Wikipedia article cited above is pretty clear. What you’re counting are called *compositions* of $n$ into $k$ parts; you’ll find more information on them [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28number_theory%29). (A search of this site for *stars and bars* will turn up many variations on this type of problem, some with quite detailed answers, but the Wikipedia [stars-and-bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29) article is your best starting point.)